# Опасности inline-вставок JavaScript

Tags: inline, логика, javascript, mvc

Подскажите, чем могут грозить инлайн вставки JS`а в отображении? Каких полезностей я могу лишиться сделав так? Или какой может быть вред?

Есть основной JS-функционал, который вынесен в отдельные файлы и есть отображение, разбитое на маленькие блоки. Идея в том, что инлайновые вставки будут реагировать на события в пределах этих блоков и обращаться к основным функциям.

*Теряюсь в догадках, какие поставить метки. Кто знает - поправьте.*

Comment: если я правильно понял, вам нужен `mediator`

Comment: А что мешает навешивать обработчики событий в коде при отображении соответствующих блоков отображения?

Раз тег стоит MVC - то и навешивать в контроллере.

Т.е. V(iew) - чистый HTML, C(ontroller) - навешиваете обработчики, M(odel) - ваши основные функции.

Хотя встречал точку зрения, что в вебе лучше паттерн MVVM использовать.

Comment: а я встречал точку зрения, что земля плоская, но это не значит, что эта точка зрения верная

Comment: @BOPOH, модели и контроллеры у меня на PHP и подмешивать туда что-либо совсем не охота  
@Spectre, про Mediator почитаю, спасибо

Comment: почитать можно здесь: [Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/) только почему-то в данный момент сайт Addy Osmani лежит

Comment: Модели и контроллеры бэкэнда не мешают написать на фронтенде MVC/MVVM JavaScript приложение со своими контроллерами, моделями и вьюхами.

Comment: @SoWa, об этом сразу как-то и не подумал. Теперь начинаю лучше понимать ответы, спасибо